# Implementation of Landweber iteration for dynamic Radon Transform in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, iteration, tomography-reconstruction, back-projection

I am working on Dynamic Inverse Problems and Radon transforms. By the term "Dynamic," I mean the object (which eventually I am going to reconstruct its image by having the its measurements), deforms as time evolves. You may imagine the Heart or the Lungs in the human body. Therefore, the usual image reconstruction tools (like filtered back-projections) need to be modified to handle the deformation. In my case, the deformation is given by a smooth function in `R^2`,

`φ^t(x,y)=(φ(t,x),φ(t,y))=(x*(1+c*x), y*(1+d*y))`

where it denotes which particle is at position`(x,y)`at the time instance`t`. Here the coefficients `c`and`d`are given by

```
c=(5.*sin(5e-5.*t*p0./pi))^(1/4), d= (5.*sin(7e-5.*t*p0./pi))^(1/4)
```

Now consider the following dynamic inverse operator (generalized Radon transform):

```
Af(s,t)=\iint_{R^2} f(φ^t(x,y)) \delta(x*cos t + y*sin t -s ) dx dy.
```

Here`\iint_{R^2}`is double integral over`R^2` and `\delta` is the usual delta function. Using a change of variable, above operator can be written as

```
g(s,t)=Af(s,t)=\iint_{R^2} J(t,x,y)f(x,y)*\delta(φ^{-1}(t,x)*cos t+φ^{-1}(t,y)*sin t-s)dxdy
```

where the inverse functions`φ^{-1}`are given by

`φ^{-1}(t,x) = (\sqrt{1+4c*x}-1)/(2c),  φ^{-1}(t,y)= (\sqrt{1+4d*y}-1)/(2d)`

and the Jacobian

`J(t,x,y)=1/(\sqrt{(1+4c*x)(1+4d*y)).`

Here`t` is a parameter which determines both time and the direction of ray (the angle). Now the function`f(φ^t (x,y))`shows the state of true object (Original Image which we call it Shepp-Logan SL) at the time instance`t`. For example when`t=0`, then the function`φ^t` is just identity, so we get `f(x,y)` which is the original image SL.

I want to do the image reconstruction with Landweber iterations as it seems it is not expensive to run compared to other methods. A Landweber iterations takes the following form

```
f^{k+1}(x,y)= f^k(x,y)+ \gamma*A^T(g-Af^k)(x,y),
```

where`\gamma`is a step length parameter let say `10^{-3}`. Here by `A^T`, I mean the adjoint of the operator`A` which is known as back projection. Therefore for a function`h`, `A^Th`will take the following form

```
A^Th(x,y)=\int_{R} J(t,x,y)*h(φ^{-1}(t,x)*cos t+φ^{-1}(t,y)*sin t,t)d t.
```

Therefore, if we replace `h` by `g-Af^k` in above adjoint equation and plug into  the Landweber iteration, we get

```
f^{k+1}(x,y)= f^k(x,y)+\gamma*\int_{R} J(t,x,y)*(g-Af^k)(φ^{-1}(t,x)*cost+φ^{-1}(t,y)*sint,t)dt.
```

Here is my goal. Let say we deform the original object SL from `t=0` to `t=5`. Then we take the Radon of the deformed SL at `t=5` which gives us the measurement at `t=5`. My friend and I have written a MATLAB code where we can deform the original object SL successfully and then we take the Radon transform (Forward problem). Now my goal is to reconstruct the original object SL at `t=0` by performing the Landweber iteration formula (given above) from the measurement of deformed SL at `t=5`. We also have written the code for this part, but we cannot reconstruct the original SL. Here are the codes:

The original Object Shepp Logan SL

```
function SLAmir = SLAmirFunc(Xsize)
% this function creates a Shepp-Logan like image
% xsize: is the desired size of the image
imageSizeX = Xsize;%100;
imageSizeY = Xsize;
[columnsInImage rowsInImage] = meshgrid(1:imageSizeX, 1:imageSizeY);
centerX = floor(Xsize/2);%50;
centerY = floor(Xsize/2);%50;
radius1 = floor(Xsize/2)-floor(Xsize/10);%40;
radius2 = floor(Xsize/2)-floor(Xsize/5.5);%32;
circlePixels_1 = (rowsInImage - centerY).^2 ./radius1.^2 ...
+ (columnsInImage - centerX).^2 ./radius2.^2<= 1;
centerX = floor(Xsize/2);
centerY = floor(Xsize/2);
radius1 = floor(Xsize/2)-floor(Xsize/7);%36;
radius2 = floor(Xsize/2)-floor(Xsize/5);%30;
circlePixels_2 = (rowsInImage - centerY).^2 ./radius1.^2 ...
+ (columnsInImage - centerX).^2 ./radius2.^2<= 1;
centerX = floor(Xsize/2);%50;
centerY = floor(Xsize/2)-floor(Xsize/7);%36;
radius = floor(centerY/3);%12;
circlePixels_3 = (rowsInImage - centerY).^2 ...
+ (columnsInImage - centerX).^2 <= radius.^2;
centerX = floor(Xsize/2)+floor(Xsize/7);%64;
centerY = floor(Xsize/2)+floor(Xsize/16);%56;
radius1 = floor(centerY/4.5);%12;
radius2 = floor(centerY/7);%8;
circlePixels_4 = (rowsInImage - centerY).^2 ./radius1.^2 ...
+ (columnsInImage - centerX).^2 ./radius2.^2<= 1;
circlePixels_4=imrotate(circlePixels_4,-30,'crop','bilinear');
centerX = floor(Xsize/2)-floor(Xsize/12.5);%42;
centerY = floor(Xsize/2)-floor(Xsize/10);%40;
radius1 = floor(centerY/2.5);%16;
radius2 = floor(centerY/4);%10;
circlePixels_5 = (rowsInImage - centerY).^2 ./radius1.^2 ...
+ (columnsInImage - centerX).^2 ./radius2.^2<= 1;
circlePixels_5=imrotate(circlePixels_5,45,'crop','bilinear');
circlePixels_6=circlePixels_1-.8.*circlePixels_2 + 0.2.*circlePixels_3 
+.4.*circlePixels_4 -.1.*circlePixels_5;
sqIy=floor(Xsize/2)-floor(Xsize/10);
sqIx=floor(Xsize/2)+floor(Xsize/5.6);
circlePixels_6 (sqIx:sqIx+4,sqIy:sqIy+4)=circlePixels_6 
(sqIx:sqIx+4,sqIy:sqIy+4)+.15;
SLAmir=circlePixels_6;
```

Forward deformation:

```
function PPN3 = NonAffineTransform_v4(P,t,p0)
%performs the non-affine transform
%t:angle
%size_p:size of the main image +50
size_p=max(size(P));
xinit=(size_p-1)/200;
xx=-xinit:0.01:xinit;
yy=xx;
k=1;
for i=1:max(size(P))
for j=1:max(size(P))
    xxO(k,:)=[xx(i),yy(j)];
    k=k+1;
end
end
k=1;
cx = (5.*sin(5e-5.*t*p0./pi))^(1/4);
cy = (5.*sin(7e-5.*t*p0./pi))^(1/4);
for i=1:max(size(P))
for j=1:max(size(P))
  xxt(k,:)= [xx(i).*((cx.*xx(i))^0+(cx.*xx(i))^1 +(cx.*xx(i))^2 +
  (cx.*xx(i))^3+(cx.*xx(i))^4), ...%+(cx.*xx(i))^2+(cx.*xx(i))^3+
  (cx.*xx(i))^4
             yy(j).*((cy.*yy(j))^0+(cy.*yy(j))^1 +(cy.*yy(j))^2 +
  (cy.*yy(j))^3+(cy.*yy(j))^4)];%+(cy.*yy(j))^2+(cy.*yy(j))^3+(cy.*yy(j))^4
  k=k+1;
end
end
PPN=zeros(size_p,size_p);
mxx1=(max(size(xx))-1);
myy1=(max(size(yy))-1);
xx_idx=round(xxO*100+floor(mxx1/2)+1);% idx correspond to original image
xxt_idx=round(xxt*100+floor(mxx1/2)+1);%idx correspond to the deformed image
for i=1:max(size(xx))*max(size(yy))
if (xxt_idx(i,1)>0 && xxt_idx(i,2)>0) && (xxt_idx(i,1)<max(size(xx))+1 && 
xxt_idx(i,2)<max(size(xx))+1)
PPN(xxt_idx(i,1),xxt_idx(i,2))=P(xx_idx(i,1),xx_idx(i,2));%.*NormPhi(i)
end
end
PPN1=PPN;
kk=0;
loopCnt=1;
while kk ~=max(size(PPN1)) 
 for j=1:max(size(xx))
     aa=find(PPN1(:,j));
     aams=max(size(aa));
         if (isempty(aa)~=1)
             AA=PPN1(aa(1):aa(aams),j);
             bb = find(AA==0);
             if (isempty(bb)~=1)
                 for i=1:max(size(bb))
                     PPN1(bb(i)+aa(1)-1,j)=PPN1(bb(i)+aa(1)-2,j);
                 end
             else
                 kk=kk+1;
             end
         else
             kk=kk+1;
         end
 end
 if j==max(size(xx)) && kk ~=max(size(PPN1))
     kk=0;
     loopCnt=loopCnt+1;
 end
 end
 % 
 PPN2=PPN1;
 kk=0;
 loopCnt=1;
 while kk ~=max(size(PPN2)) 
 for j=1:max(size(xx))
     aa=find(PPN2(j,:));
     aams=max(size(aa));
         if (isempty(aa)~=1)
             AA=PPN2(j,aa(1):aa(aams));
             bb = find(AA==0);
             if (isempty(bb)~=1)
                 for i=1:max(size(bb))
                     PPN2(j,bb(i)+aa(1)-1)=PPN2(j,bb(i)+aa(1)-2);
                 end
             else
                 kk=kk+1;
             end
         else
             kk=kk+1;
         end
 end
 if j==max(size(xx)) && kk ~=max(size(PPN2))
     kk=0;
     loopCnt=loopCnt+1;
 end
 end 
 PPN3=PPN2;%.*NormPhi;%./sum(NormPhi(:));
```

Inverse deformation:

```
function fxy = invNonAffineTransform_v41(g,sp,t,tt,x,y,dxx)
p0=300;
ts=max(size(t));
xs=max(size(x));
ys=max(size(y));
temp=0;
mxx1=(max(size(x))-1);
myy1=(max(size(y))-1);
fxy=zeros(xs,ys);
for i=1:xs
for j=1:ys
    for k=1:ts
        cx = (5.*sin(5e-5.*t(k)*p0./pi))^(1/4);%(t(k)+pi/2)
        cy = (5.*sin(7e-5.*t(k)*p0./pi))^(1/4);
        invphix = (sqrt(1+4.*cx.*x(i))-1)./(2.*cx);
        invphiy = (sqrt(1+4.*cy.*y(j))-1)./(2.*cy);
        Stemp = invphix.*cos(t(k)+pi/2)+ invphiy.*sin(t(k)+pi/2);
        %StempIdx= floor(Stemp./dxx);
        StempIdx = floor(Stemp.*100);
        spIdx=find(sp==StempIdx);
        J=sqrt(1/((1+2.*cx.*x(i)).*(1+2.*cy.*y(j))));
        if isempty(spIdx)
            temp=temp+0;
        else
            temp = temp +J.*g(spIdx,k);
        end
    end
     fxy(i,j) = fxy(i,j)+ tt.*temp;
     temp =0;
end
end
```

Run:

```
clear all
clc
close all
size_p=151;
P=zeros(size_p,size_p);
DisSide=40;
P1 = SLAmirFunc(size_p-DisSide);%
P(DisSide/2+1:size_p-DisSide/2,DisSide/2+1:size_p-DisSide/2)=P1;
p0=300;
size_p=max(size(P));
xinit=(size_p-1)/200;
xx=-xinit:0.01:xinit;
yy=xx;
j=1;
tt=[25:5:300].*pi./p0;
fxy=P;
for i=1:max(size(tt))
PPN3p = NonAffineTransform_v4(fxy,tt(i),p0);
PPN3 = PPN3p;
figure;imagesc(PPN3), colormap(bone), colorbar;
end
ttdeg=tt.*180./pi;
[g,sp] = radon(PPN3,ttdeg);
I1 = iradon(g,ttdeg,size_p);
Afpre=zeros(max(size(sp)),max(size(tt)));
fold=zeros(size_p,size_p);
stepsize=0.0001;
ssp=max(size(sp));
dxx=(xx(size_p)-xx(1)+1)/ssp;
Dt=tt(2)-tt(1);
for it=1:10
g1=g-Afpre;
fnew = fold + stepsize.*invNonAffineTransform_v41(g1,sp,tt,Dt,xx,yy,dxx);
for i=1:max(size(tt))
PPN3p = NonAffineTransform_v4(fnew,tt(i),p0);
clear PPN3
PPN3 = PPN3p;   
end
[Afpre,sp] = radon(PPN3,ttdeg);
fold = fnew;
end
```

I was wondering if anyone here is familiar with this topic and can be any help.

If this is not clear please comment, and I will be answering your questions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the code and equations, maybe someone can make sense of them. We won't know till you post them. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your comment. I have now posted all the math and Matlab codes. Thank you

Comment: I think an answer to this is a research paper. I myself have a paper in reconstruction of dynamic CT scans. I doubt you will find the answer in Stackoverflow, its arguably an andvanced research method... I will try to have a look at this question some time next week (if its not closed by then)

Comment: @Ander Biguri Thanks for reading my problem and commenting. I would be very happy to see your idea. If you think would be easier you can reach at me at my email srabieni@purdue.edu and we can discuss. Thanks again.

Comment: @SiamakRabienia your code does not run, there are few errorrs, e.g.: Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in NonAffineTransform_v4 (line 21)

Comment: Also, reading your maths a bit again, your proposal looks the same as what Simon Rit proposes in few papers and I worked on during my PhD. You can have a look at my paper (I am using my real name) if you are interested.